# Quick Edit module permissions

Tags: 8, blocks, users, entities

I have enabled Quick Edit module on my Drupal 8 website and it's working ok, I have edit link in the toolbar to show all edit icons for edit menu on page.

Problem is in new user role. I have new user role and I enabled `Access in-place editing` permission for users in this role, but there is no option to edit anything on the page or edit link in toolbar.

What I'm missing? Is there some additional permission that I need to grant for this role (they already have permission to administer blocks)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the problem, it's stupid.

I forgot to add permission to access to contextual links for this user role, so that's it.